# Retain the dropdown value after the page is refresh or move to another page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

let me explain my scenario. I am having the dropdownlist in my master page. if changed dropdownlist the data are changed depend upon the dropdownlist value.
If i refreshed my page or moved to another page the dropdownlist will clear automatically.

I want to retain the dropdownlist value after refresh the page or moved to another page.

I tried like this but this is not help ful.

HTML

```
<select id="Facility_ID" required typeof="text" name="Facility Name" ng-options="Role.FacilityName for Role in Roles"
                    form="DistanceMatrixFormId" class="form-control" ng-model="Role._id" ng-selected="getFacilityID(Role._id.FacilityName)">
            </select>
```

Controller.js

```
 $scope.getFacilityID = function (data) {
     localStorage.setItem("FacilityName", data);
     var getfacility = localStorage.getItem("FacilityName");
 }
```

[i refered this link but it is not help ful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171840/keep-selected-value-of-drop-down-list-after-page-refresh)

I don't know how to retain the value. can any one fixed me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put an object into the local storage, you must store strings inside local storage.

If you want, you can have an implementation I did here : [How to add local storage in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269639/how-to-add-local-storage-in-angular/34271742#34271742)

For your current code, you don't need to use ng-selected. ng-model is enough.

```
<select id="Facility_ID" required typeof="text" 
        name="Facility Name" 
        ng-options="Role.FacilityName for Role in Roles"
        form="DistanceMatrixFormId" 
        class="form-control" 
        ng-model="Role._id"
        ng-change="updateLocalStorage()">
</select>
```

And inside your angular controller, what you can do is the following :

```
myApp.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', 'LocalStorageService',
     function($scope, LocalStorageService){

     // After initialization of your "Role" object

     $scope.Role._id = LocalStorageService.retrieve('mySelectValue');

     $scope.updateLocalStorage = function(){
         LocalStorageService.store('mySelectValue', $scope.Role._id);
     }

}])
```

Comment: Hi Deblaton Jean-philippe: I got this error [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/unpr?p0=LocalStorageServiceProvider%20%3C-%20LocalStorageService%20%3C-%20UserNameShowCtrl

Comment: Do i have to add any js for localstorageservice in my proj

Comment: @Vinoth Then `JSON.stringify` them

Comment: @Vinoth In my answer I provided you a link to a LocalStorageService I wrote 2 years ago. My answer here illustrate how to use it in your case. So yes, you need to create a service like I did in the answer I linked

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe: not open anything in my UI.  I got error in my controller.js page. _id is undefined.

Comment: @Vinoth I need more information. At what line is the '_id' undefined? Maybe you can do `LocalStorageService.store('mySelectValue', $scope.Role._id || '');`

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example that uses a service to store the selected value. Unfortunately the embedded demo does not work because of the sandboxing, but works when served as an application.

```js
angular.module(
  "App", []
).factory("MyStorage", function() {
  const key = "selected";
  return {
    getValue: function() {
      const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
      return stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : null;
    },
    setValue: function(value) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
  };
}).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, MyStorage) {
  $scope.options = ["A", "B", "C"];
  $scope.selected = MyStorage.getValue();
  $scope.$watch("selected", newValue => {
    MyStorage.setValue(newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="x for x in options">
  </select>
</div>
```